Use Swift AppIntents/Shortcuts with SwiftData for Siri to prompt for multiple new record fields. Save the record to with the user responses
I am trying to setup Shortcuts and AppIntents to allow a user to summon Siri and open a dialog to create a new record with two or more SwiftData model attributes. I have successfully coded for Siri to open the app and for Siri to open the app and navigate to the page to add a record but have been unable to capture a user response from a Siri prompt and save that to a new records. If this is covered in the Apple docs and examples, I have not been able to find it.
Here's what I have so far:
@Model
class Thing {

    var name: String = ""
    var comment: String = "no comment"
    var recordType: String = "0"
    var count: Int = 0

    init(name: String, comment: String, recordType: String, count: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.comment = comment
        self.recordType = recordType
        self.count = count
    }
    
}//class

struct CreateNewThing: AppIntent {
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Create New Thing"
    static var description = IntentDescription("Opens the app and moves to the Add Thing screen.")
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = true

    @AppStorage("navigateToThingAddView") private var navigateToThingAddView: Bool = false

    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        navigateToThingAddView = true
        return .result()
    }
}//create new thing

struct ThingAddDialog: AppIntent {

    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Add Thing Dialog"
    static var description = IntentDescription("Prompt the user for a name and comment for a new Thing.")
    
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = true
    
    @Parameter(title: "Name", default: "")
    var name: String

    @Parameter(title: "Comment", default: "No comment")
    var comment: String

    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some ProvidesDialog & ShowsSnippetView {
        // Logic to navigate to the Add Thing dialog view
        //navigateToThingDialog = true

        let dialog = IntentDialog(
          full: "What is the name of the new Thing?",
          supporting: "I have opened the Add Thing Dialog.")

         let answer = $name.needsValueError("Provide a name")
        name = answer.description
        
        saveThing(name: name, comment: comment)
        return .result(dialog: dialog)

    }
    
    @MainActor
    private func saveThing(name: String, comment: String) {

        let newThing = Thing(name: name, comment: comment, recordType: "0", count: 0)
        
        // Add newThing to SwiftData 
        let container = try! ModelContainer(for: Thing.self)
        container.mainContext.insert(newThing)
        
        try? container.mainContext.save()
    }
}

struct ThingShortcuts: AppShortcutsProvider {
    static var shortcutTileColor = ShortcutTileColor.navy
    
    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
        
            AppShortcut(
                intent: CreateNewThing(),
                phrases: [
                    "Create a new Thing in \(.applicationName)"
                ],
                shortTitle: "Create a Thing",
                systemImageName: "document.badge.plus"
            )
        
             AppShortcut(
                intent: ThingAddDialog(),
                phrases: ["Add Dialog in \(.applicationName)"],
                shortTitle: "Add Thing Dialog",
                systemImageName: "plus.square"
        )
        
    }//var
}//thing shortcuts

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 16.1, iOS 18.1
